# Rejection Sampling: the bound and the implementation with R

Tags: bayesian, rejection-sampling

I've been reading about rejection sampling for Bayesian Statistics, and I have the following example:

Given $y\sim N(\theta,1)$ , $p(\theta)\sim Cauchy(0,1)$, 
$q(\theta |y)=p(\theta |y)p(\theta )$, $g(\theta )\sim N(y,1)$ and y=1

Then, the example says: $\frac { q(\theta |y) }{ g(\theta ) } =\frac { exp\left\{ -\frac { { (y-\theta ) }^{ 2 } }{ 2 }  \right\} \cdot \frac { 1 }{ 1+{ \theta  }^{ 2 } }  }{ \frac { 1 }{ \sqrt { 2\pi  }  } exp\left\{ -\frac { { (\theta -y) }^{ 2 } }{ 2 }  \right\}  } =\frac { \sqrt { 2\pi  }  }{ 1+{ \theta  }^{ 2 } } \le \sqrt { 2\pi  }$
$ \\ $

I understand almost everything, but the last step is not so clear for me (the inequality), because according that, $M=\sqrt { 2\pi  } \\$

But I read the following definition: $M=\underset { \theta  }{ sup } \quad \frac { q(\theta |y) }{ g(\theta ) } $, and I think $M=\frac{\sqrt { 2\pi  } }{2}$

My second doubt is about the implementation Of this example with R. Assuming the first M, I use the following code

```
th<-rep(NA,1000)
i<-0
while(i<1000){
theta1<-rnorm(1,1,1)
u<-runif(1)
if(u<=1/(1+(theta1^2))){
i<-i+1
th[i]<-theta1
}
}
th
hist(th)
```

Am I implementing it in the correct way? Is it correct my histogram of the posterior? I

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The first question is unclear:** The inequality$$\dfrac{q(y|\theta)}{g(\theta)}=1\big/\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}{\{1+\theta^2\}}=\dfrac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{1+\theta^2}\le \sqrt{2\pi}$$ is correct when using $q(y|\theta)=\exp\{-(\theta-y)^2/2\}\big/\{1+\theta^2\}$ instead of the properly normalised density (which normalisation constant is not known in closed form). *How would you derive that the upper bound is $\sqrt{2\pi}/2$ instead?*

**Checking your algorithm produces the right answer is straightforward:** add the target density on top of your histogram:

[image]

which is produced by the following R code

```
pos<-function(x){dnorm(x,1,1)*dcauchy(x)}
normaz=integrate(pos,-50,150)$val
hist(th,prob=TRUE,nclass=57,col="wheat")
curve(pos(x)/normaz,add=TRUE,lwd=2,col="sienna3")
```

Comment: You're right... I was evaluating $\frac{\sqrt(2\pi)}{1+ {\theta}^{2}}$ at the MLE (1 in this case). Thanks a lot!